# Electron Global Variables or DB

Tags: javascript, database, variables, electron

Im rather new to electron programming using JS, however i have a fair bit of experience in JS itself which is entirely what electron uses however im having a bit of an issue. Im noticing a problem trying to use what i would call "global variables". I have multiple BrowserWindows that need to be used in this application. One for the initial login screen, and one for the main window. Once im authenticated, at this time through firebase, i want to hide the login screen and show the main window. It doesnt seem theres really a way to do this. I am natively  a C# dev so im probably confusing myself with things that dont exist in a different language, however any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `BrowserWindows` have isolated scopes (since they are browser instances), therefore you **can't** have a global variable shared between all the browser windows. However, on your `main` application (the electron main process) which **hosts** all the `renderers`, you may declare a global variable and gain access to it using the IPC channel. Otherwise, you may just look for any tutorial about electron and a database.

Comment: thank you. Im thinking that a DB might be the way to go. I will have to research how to use IPC channels though. Perhaps thats the best idea. Thanks.

Comment: It's just like a "socket" (in fact, you can use socket.io as well). Take a look at the official docs: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer (<-- this one will be used on the browser window) and https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main (<-- this one will be used on the main process). Basically, the main process fetches informations and responds to the renderer process when data is requested. Otherwise, you can just access a shared DB. Take a look at this: https://www.techiediaries.com/electron-data-persistence/